# SAML post example using Java

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0

I'm in process of consuming the SAML post request using Java.

Here I need to construct on SAML request and need to send the same to SAML sos server, I'm not sure how we can achieve it using Java as i checked with **httpPost** client and related stuff, but I didn't get any success for the same.

Can anyone guide me how I can consume SAML based SSO request using Java?

Thanks,
Kuldeep

Comment: I.E mentioned is my SAML request, so how i can send a SAML post request using Java?

Comment: are you POSTing from an SP to an IdP or from an IdP to an SP?

Comment: Hey, I'm requesting from SP to IDP, currently I got success to to reach the IDP and also can able to login successfully, but my another question is, How I can manage the session for the same for all the subsequent request after login?

Comment: login at the IdP and login at the SP are not related. They're completely separate events. When the attributes arrive at your app in a SAML Response you can use, e.g. the eduPersonTargetedId attribute as a persistent identifier in a JSESSIONID cookie at your app and store other relevant information from the SAML Response. The Assertion in the Response will have a time to live so you can use that to limit the validity of the session at your app. When the session expires, just send the user back to the IdP to get a new IdP login event and attributes sent to your app to create a new JSESSIONID

Answer (score 0):

You would need to read the SAMLResponse from the Body of the Http Post Request like you'd read any other value sent in a form and then use appropriate libraries like XMLBeans to parse and read the value of XML. 
The value comes as base64 encoded, so first you will decode it, then parse the XML, then verify the XML Signature (if required) and then use the values.
One example is given here: https://github.com/oaeproject/SAMLParser/blob/master/src/main/java/org/sakaiproject/SAMLParser/SAMLParser.java

I would recommend you to understand how SAML 2.0 works before implementing it, I found the wikipedia article for that quite helpful : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML_2.0